# Listview on worksheet generates cannot insert object error Excel 2010

Tags: vba, listview, excel, excel-2010

Hi I have an Excel 2003 application which has a listview embedded in the worksheet.  It no longer works on Excel 2010.

I re-registered the ocx using `regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX` as per advice.

This works for listviews on forms, but not for the worksheet.

Microsoft advises that Cannot insert object can be generated if the control is form specific and an attempt is made to add to the worksheet.

1. Can the listview be used in Excel 2010 on a worksheet
2. If so how?

Otherwise a rewrite will be required.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

That happened to my Excel files using ActiveX or any sort of automation. The solution was confused at the beginning but the following link will help you.

1. Create a batch to remove cached control type libraries (extender files *.EXD) files from Windows
2. Opening each of the projects (Excel with macros)
3. Switch the file to design mode
4. Open  VBA Code (Alt-F11) to edit any module and press from the main menu   > Debug > Compile VBAProject
5. Switch back to Run Mode
6. Save and Close File
7. Reopen the file & test

[Form Controls stop working after December 2014 Updates](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2014/12/11/forms-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates-.aspx)